# Can holders of a residence permit issued by an EU/EFTA state enter Hungary if Hungary has opened its borders to the nationals of that state?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, paperwork, covid-19, hungary

Sorry for the clumsy title (edits would be appreciated).

Hungary has now relaxed the control at internal borders. According to [the US embassy in Hungary](https://hu.usembassy.gov/covid-19/), Citizens from neighbouring EU countries (Austria, the Czech Republic, Serbia, Slovenia, Slovakia, Croatia, with the exception of Romania) as well as Germany, Switzerland, Lichtenstein, Norway, and Iceland can now enter Hungary without restrictions.

According to [the Swiss embassy](https://www.eda.admin.ch/budapest), citizens of all EU/EFTA states and Serbia can now enter Hungary without restrictions since June 18.

Unfortunately, I have not been able to find an official Hungarian source on these to see if (temporary or permanent) residence permit holders from e.g. Austria (neighbouring) or Switzerland (not neighbouring) can enter Hungary in a similar manner as the nationals of those countries.

For example, [this press release](http://abouthungary.hu/news-in-brief/coronavirus-update-home-quarantine-rules-relaxed-for-many-new-countries/) says

> During today’s Operational Group press conference, Róbert Kiss, Lieutenant Colonel of the Hungarian Police Force, reported that people can now enter Hungary from the Czech Republic, Germany, Austria, Slovakia, Serbia, Slovenia and from Friday Croatia without the need for compulsory home quarantine.

without specifying citizenship/residence/etc.

The [border information on the Hungarian police website](http://www.police.hu/hu/hirek-es-informaciok/legfrissebb-hireink/hatarrendeszet/tajekoztatas-information) appears to have not been updated since June 12, it only mentioned exceptions for neighbouring states but not other EU/EFTA countries.

Answer (score 3):

Per TIMATIC, the database used by airlines:

> - Passengers are not allowed to enter.
> - This does not apply to nationals of Austria, Belgium,    Bulgaria, Croatia, Cyprus, Czechia, Denmark, Estonia,    Finland, France,
>   Germany, Greece, Hungary, Ireland (Rep.),    Italy, Latvia,
>   Liechtenstein, Lithuania, Luxembourg, Malta,    Netherlands, Norway,
>   Poland, Portugal, Romania, Serbia,    Slovakia, Slovenia, Spain,
>   Sweden and Switzerland.
> - This does not apply to family members of nationals Austria,    Belgium, Bulgaria, Croatia, Cyprus, Czechia, Denmark,    Estonia,
>   Finland, France, Germany, Greece, Hungary, Ireland    (Rep.), Italy,
>   Latvia, Liechtenstein, Lithuania,    Luxembourg, Malta, Netherlands,
>   Norway, Poland, Portugal,    Romania, Serbia, Slovakia, Slovenia,
>   Spain, Sweden and    Switzerland.
> - This does not apply to nationals of Japan and Korea (Rep.)    travelling on business.
> - This does not apply to passengers with a signed and stamped    letter issued by the Deputy-Chief Officer of the National    Police.

So no, foreign EU/Schengen residents are **not** allowed except family members of EU/Schengen citizens